# css header title and sidebar navigation issue in html5

Tags: css, html

This is my html5 code:

```
 <header id="header">
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" id="logo">
    <h1>The Articles</h1>
 </header>
 <section id="section">
    <article class="article">

          <img src="img/articles.png" alt="articles" />
          <p class="comments">
             by<span class="woo"> JOHN WOO</span> 
             <date>June 04, 2013, 22 Comments</date>
          </p>
          <h1 class="issue">Issue No 376</h1>
          <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amer, consectetur adipising elit Vestibulum eu ligula justo, ullamcorper viverraest. Donec viverra libero in tellus ullamcorper lobortis,. Nam nunc metus, molestie sit amet sagitis et, hendrenit quam. Ut hendrerit commodo nunc, eu euismod odio egestas a. Morbi felis lorem, convallis id scelerisque eget, faucibus eget lectus.</p>
          <p class="dev-express">asp.net, .net, dev-express</p>
          <a href="#" class="myButton">More</a>

       <div class="border-bottom"></div>
       <div class="article1">
          <img src="img/cat.png" alt="" />
          <p class="comments">
             by <span class="woo">JOHN WOO</span> 
             <date>June 04, 2013, 22 Comments</date>
          </p>
          <h1 class="issue">Issue No 375</h1>
          <p class="lorem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amer, consectetur adipising elit Vestibulum eu ligula justo, ullamcorper viverraest. Donec viverra libero in tellus ullamcorper lobortis,. Nam nunc metus, molestie sit amet sagitis et, hendrenit quam. Ut hendrerit commodo nunc, eu euismod odio egestas a. Morbi felis lorem, convallis id scelerisque eget, faucibus eget lectus.</p>
          <p class="dev-express">asp.net, .net, dev-express</p>
          <a href="#" class="myButton">More</a>
       </div>

    </article>
    </section>
```

This is my JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/y3x8zqav/

Now my web-page look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmIys.jpg

In my page i marked, that header title and aside bar navigation need to place same line.

Is this correct format for located navigation in aside?

or may i know css property to fix this?

Any help would be highly appreciated..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want the nav links after "the articles" ?

Comment: That is my doubt.. but i need title "the articles and navigation is place to same line..so where to place nav links, in article or aside?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your web site, you need add a couple of changes. Here's the css code to add:

```
.aside {
   margin-top: -80px;
}

.aside > img {
   margin-top: 25px;
}
```

That's it;

Comment: I know this method of changes.. but i need some standard css property.. and from your answer didn't get still..

Comment: As already your website is almost rendered with many css styles to different elements and are linked to each other so it will disturb other elements positioning too, so I provided a quick solution.